# Prove that $A \cdot B \cdot C = B:\left( {A \otimes C} \right)$?

Tags: inner-products, tensor-products, tensors

I am confused about the following identity. Let A, B, and C be second-order tensors:

$A \cdot B \cdot C = B:\left( {A \otimes C} \right)$

where ⋅, : and ⊗ denote the inner product, double dot product, and dyadic product respectively.
This "identity" can be observed in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmth.png) taken from https://doi.org/10.1115/1.4034024
I will deeply appreciate your comments and any sources. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just write down the interpretation in Einstein's notation?

Comment: It would be helpful to state the definitions of $A\cdot B, A:B, A\otimes B$ explicitly in your post, especially since the referenced article is behind a paywall.

Comment: Also, is it being assumed that $A,B,C$ are symmetric tensors? If so then this makes the precise definitions of the products less important.